# How to make a 3D stacked bar chart using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, stacked-bar-chart

I have this dataframe:

```
Name <- c("Present", "Extra", "Updated")
Gyor <- c(94143, 13691,12661)
Agglomeration <- c(58462, 20669, 6613)
df <- data.frame(Name, Gyor, Agglomeration)
print(df)
```

What I would like to have is a 3D stacked bar plot like this (using ggplot)

[image: 3dplot]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate 3D plots using `ggplot`. There are some extension packages which *sort of* allow it, but this type of plot is very much against the entire ethos of `ggplot`. It would be considered a *terrible* way to present data by modern data visualisation standards; it is difficult to read off accurately and looks very dated.

In addition, the data in your question can be easily plotted as a 2d stacked bar (it doesn't have enough dimensions to allow a 3D stacked bar like the one you have included)

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(pivot_longer(df, -Name), aes(Name, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_brewer(NULL, palette = 'Set1') +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: So what is it that you want to change?

Comment: I mean I did the 2D graph, what you just proposed. But I do not know how to do the 3D one in R. The above graph was done by a colleague in Python, but since I am an R person, I wanted to write a code for this in R.